# If the sides of a triangle are in the ratio of $2:4:5,$ then how to construct a similar triangle whose base is $3$ cm?

Tags: geometry

Problem:
If the sides of a triangle are in the ratio of $2:4:5,$ then how to construct a similar triangle whose base is $3$ cm?

Solution:
Multiply $2$ by $2,$ $4$ by $2$ and $5$ by $2$ we get $4,8$ and $10$ respectively. So,we get three sides $4,8$ and $10$ as a similar triangle as that of a triangle whose sides are in the ratio of $2:4:5.$

But the question says that the construct a triangle whose base is $3$ cm.So, what about the base $3?$

Comment: Just scale stuff up by a fractional part. Multiply by 1.5 for instance

Comment: How did you get $1.5?$

Comment: Well, 1.5 = 3/2, so when you multiply 2 by 3/2 it becomes 3, which is one of the required bases.

Comment: So,the solution,which I have mentioned,is incorrect?

Comment: So you mean to say $3$ can be any side of the triangle?

Comment: Well you want a side length of 3, so your solution is incorrect yea

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply 2 by 3/2, 4 by 3/2, and 5 by 3/2 to get 3: 6: 7.5. This triangle has the same ratio as 2:4:5 and has a base of 3.

Comment: So,the solution which I have mentioned,is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the solution you have in incorrect.

Comment: But it is given everywhere in the internet,even in India's best scientific book 'NCERT'?

Comment: Does your solution give you a base of 3 cm?

Comment: @Vulch can you link the 'NCERT' which you are talking about?